# How can I get my favorite people (outlook contacts) via Microsoft Graph

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api

I want to use the Microsoft Graph to receive my favorite people (outlook contacts) I set in Outlook.

In Outlook I can right-click any contact and choose `Add to Favorites`, then they are shown in Outlook in the bottom right corner. To see the my favorites I had to enable them in Outlook via `View -> To-Do Bars -> People`. Then it looks like following:

[image: Picture of Favorites]

The closest to my goal is the `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/people` endpoint, but there are only my recent contacts listed, not necessarily my favorites.

In the documentation of the people endpoint (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/people-example) there is the property `isFavorite` but seems always to be `false`. Also the Filter `?$filter=isFavorite eq true` fails with:

```
"error": {
        "code": "ErrorInvalidProperty",
        "message": "The property 'isFavorite' does not support filtering."
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tested this out and got the same response, looks like this is not supported yet. Would you consider [filing a feature request on the M365 developer platform](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-developer-platform/idb-p/Microsoft365DeveloperPlatform) so this can be looked into?

You might also consider doing a `select` with the desired parameters in the meantime and doing the filtering client-side?

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/people?$select=displayName,isFavorite
```

[image: isFavouriteSelectClientSide]

Please let me know if this helps and if you have further questions.

Answer (score 0):

On the low level, it is stored as a hidden distribution list.
I think only Extended MAPI can get there...